# HASHBYTES should return a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, converters

I wrote a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HashConvert
(
   @value varchar(max)
   @len int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
BEGIN
   declare @h varchar(max)

   set @h = convert(varchar(@len), hashbytes("sha1", substring(@value, 1, @len))
   /*other code*/
END
```

Can I use `convert` is this way? I need `h` to have a length equal to `@len`

```
set @h = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA1', SUBSTRING(@value, 1, @len)),2),1,@len)
```

Is it ok? Or better to use `varchar(22)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable as a length specification for varchar type. Just use `varchar(max)` as a variable datatype and you'll be OK.